# Spring security intercept URL not working for single page application

Tags: angularjs, spring-security

here is my spring security file:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="isAnonymous()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/stat" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/articles" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <form-login login-page="/index.html#/login"
            default-target-url="/index.html#/articles"
            authentication-failure-url="/index.html#/login?error"
            username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/index.html#/login?logout" />
    </http>
```

here I am mentioning the intercept URL '/**' at last only.

Below is my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:dispatcher-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- for spring security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring-security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

but still I am getting the redirection issue, the /login and other url patterns are not getting mapped onto the handler!

here is the app.js :

```
searchApp.config([ '$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/articles', {
        templateUrl : 'partials/articles-list-accordian.html',
        controller : 'ArticlesController'
    }).when('/login', {
        templateUrl : 'partials/login.html',
        controller : 'LoginControllers'
    }).when('/stat', {
        templateUrl : 'partials/job-stat.html',
        controller : 'JobStatController'
    }).otherwise({
        /*redirectTo : '/welcome'*/
        redirectTo : '/articles'
    });
} ]);
```

Please guide me here, i am newbie is spring security, thus might be making some silly mistakes..

Comment: Are you trying to intercept client side routing in server?

Comment: Sorry for the delay @RaghuVenmarathoor  No normal server side routing only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a great tutorial for applying spring security with AngularJS, it is definitely not trivial, you'll have to do some changes in your app.

For example, it is recommended to use the httpBasic security rather than the formLogin authentication method. you'll also need to send your credentials to your server using in HTTP header the content should be encoded.

you can read how to do it right here:

https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/

I already succeeded to implement it with the specified technologies stack, if you'll need further help let me know.

Comment: Ohh I got it now! yaa its not trivial at all! and along with ur mentioned url I found  [This_link](https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/12/the-login-page-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-ii)  usefull as well. 
I will come back to the comments with more doubts (if any) Thanks..